# Python code works okay via terminal, but not via wsgi script. ( TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable )

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Full script:

```
import pprint

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    aaa = ['a','b','c']
    pprint.pprint(aaa)
```

If I were to run this in the terminal it'd be...

```
>>> import pprint
>>> aaa = ['a','b','c']
>>> pprint.pprint(aaa)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

As you can see it works fine. But via wsgi-script it does not work.

error_log:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

BTW is "pprint" the "print_r()" equivalence in PHP?

Comment: :-) You're not as clever, or as covert, as you think you are, Sumer. But I do edit questions a lot for style, and this one hasn't gone south yet.

Comment: Upvoted, reasonable question; the "return a response as an iterable" pattern is not very intuitive for any people used to do CGI, php

Answer (score 9):

`WSGI` requires that you *return* the output you want to send back to a browser as the return value of your function, not just print it out. So you'd need to use `pprint.pformat()` and `return` its result, rather than `pprint.pprint` (which just tries to print it out via `print` - not what you want here).

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    aaa = ['a','b','c']
    return pprint.pformat(aaa)
```